# Dateutil Parser return datetime object when it should have returned None

Tags: python, python-dateutil

While trying to parse a date from a string, `dateutil` parser returns current date when it should have returned `ParserError`. This is when `fuzzy` parameter is set to `True`.

For example:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("March, 2022", fuzzy = True)
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 27, 0, 0)
```

Here I want it to return `ParserError` since the day part is not present.

Comment: What makes you say it should have returned `None`? Per [the docs](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) it looks like it _always_ returns a `datetime.datetime` (unless: 1. it throws an error; or 2. `fuzzy_with_tokens` is set, in which case a `tuple`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited the questions. How do I change the way it should behave when day is not present I want it to throw parse error and not default value

Comment: Read the docs I linked to above - _"This module attempts to be forgiving with regards to unlikely input formats, returning a datetime object even for dates which are ambiguous."_ It uses sensible defaults (or an override you supply) for missing data rather than throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it returns a value is because the parser assumes a default day of the current day when the day part is not specified.

Also if the date is invalid, the parse raises a ParserError and does not return None

Comment: I have edited the questions. How do I change the way it should behave when day is not present I want it to throw parse error and not default value